# how to distinguish expect script return normally or by timeout

Tags: timeout, return-value, expect

I have following expect command which may return normally or by timeout. Is there a way to distinguish the two cases?

```
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" {set timeout 60; eval spawn ./bin/stop.sh; interact }'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can expect key word 'timeout' and 'eof' means spawned process returned, eg.
    expect {
    timeout {action}
    eof {other action}
    }